# Rails plugin for VIm

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, vim

http://bit.ly/18j9Ksx

I've seen this video and I like this editor. Where can I find such Vim theme and plugin for navigation over directories's column?

Comment: Look at http://vim.org.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [Rails.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails) which enables the support for Rails framework along with the [CodeSchool theme](http://astonj.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/codeschool.vim2_.zip).

Further read here: [astonj blog post about Vim for Rails](http://astonj.com/tech/vim-for-ruby-rails-and-a-sexy-theme/?utm_source=rubyweekly&utm_medium=email)

Answer (score 0):

that's [NERDtree](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1658) for the directory navigation and [Rails.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-rails) is the de facto standard rails plugin. Not sure about the theme, but there are hundreds on vim.org.